# creating a matrix,whose size is similar to a given matrix but all elements are identical

Tags: matlab

I have a n/n matrix A.

Now I want to create a new matrix B which has same size as A but with all 2.

Example :

If `A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9 ]`, B becomes `B = [ 2 2 2; 2 2 2; 2 2 2 ]` .

Comment: `B = repmat(2, size(A));`

Comment: or `B = zeros(size(A)) +2 ;`

Comment: or B = 2*ones(size(A));